# How to properly use a Reactor Publisher

Tags: java, spring, reactor, project-reactor

I can´t figure out how to properly implement a Publisher/Subscriber scenario with Reactor. I have a working solution, but the implementation does not seem correct to me:

My problem is that I need to manually implement the publisher to register the subscriber and pass the events:

```
public void publishQuotes(String ticker) throws InterruptedException {

// [..] Here I generate some "lines" to be publisher

for (Subscriber<? super String> subscriber : subscribers) {
    lineList.forEach(line -> subscriber.onNext(line));
}

}

@Override
public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
    subscribers.add(subscriber);

}
```

Then, I have a WorkQueue Processor (that should be the consumer):

```
WorkQueueProcessor<String> sink = WorkQueueProcessor.create();

// Here I subscribe to my publiser
publisher.subscribe(sink);

// Creates a Reactive Stream from the processor (having converted the lines to Quotations)
Flux<StockQuotation> mappedRS = sink.map(quotationConverter::convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation);

// Here I perform a number of stream transformations 

// Each call to consume will be executed in a separated Thread
filteredRS.consume(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " data=" + i));
```

It works fine but is ugly as hell. [In this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/) taken from the Spring Guides, they use an EventBus to route the events from the publisher to the consumer but, when I try to link it with my processor I get this compiler error:

```
eventBus.on($("quotes"),sink);

The method on(Selector, Consumer<T>) in the type EventBus is not applicable for the arguments (Selector<String>, WorkQueueProcessor<String>)
```

I´m lost here, what would be the best way to link a publisher with a Processor? Would you recommend using an EventBus? If so, what would be the proper invokation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the EventBus, you will publish your lines via

```
 eventBus.notify("quotes", Event.wrap(line);
```

And subscribe via

```
eventBus.on($("quotes"), e -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " data=" + e);
```

where "e" is of Type Event<String>.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan.I was confused with the type to which I had to subscribe. If I use `WorkQueueProcessor<Event<String>>` it works just fine.